# Relation between linearly independent solutions and their wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $y_1(x)=x^3$ and $y_2(x)=x^2|x|$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following statements:

> $(P)$ $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent solutions of $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4x\frac{dy}{dx}+6y=0$ on  $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> $(Q)$ The Wronskian $y_1(x)\frac{dy_2}{dx}(x)-y_2(x)\frac{dy_1}{dx}(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then which of the above statements hold true.

The question appears in GATE-$2017$. I am trying this problem in following steps:

**Both $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are solutions:** First I checked that $y_1(x)$ is a solution of above ODE. For $y_2(x)$, I checked that it is differentiable and $y_2(x)=x^3$ is a solution  for $x\geq0$ and $y_2(x)=-x^3$ is a solution  for $x<0$ of the above ODE.

**Find their Wronskian:** For $x\geq0$; $w(y_1,y_2)=w(x^3,x^3)=0$ and for $x<0$; $w(y_1,y_2)=w(x^3,-x^3)=0$. Thus Wronskian of $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ is zero for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ both are solutions of the above ODE and their Wronskian is zero for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then can we conclude $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linealy dependent? But the answer is given both $(P)$ and $(Q)$ are true. I am stuck here.

If the solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent then how can we show this.

Comment: Consider the sum $a x^3 +  b x^2 |x| = 0$, for $x \in \mathbb R$ and show that the only coefficients which satisfy this are $a = b = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

> If two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ of an ODE are linearly dependent, then the Wronskian $w(y_1,y_2)=0$.

The converse of this fact is false, and you just found a counterexample to show it is false.

So there is no problem that both $(P)$ and $(Q)$ are true.

---

The only thing you still need to do is show that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Did you mean: If the Wronskian $w(y_1,y_2)=0$ then the solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ may not be linearly dependent and the above ODE with these solutions is counterexample.

Comment: Thats not what the converse of a statement is. If a statement reads "if A then B", the converse is "if B then A". This translates to If the Wronskian is 0, then the two solutions are linearly dependent.

As Phenotype mentioned, this statement is false (you have a counterexample in your OP).